# How to access a prepopulated SQLite database built into a Xamarin.forms app?

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need my app to contain a **prepopulated** database that is created outside the app, that the app can use and update.

It seems like a basic necessity, I expected it would be easy like this:

- Add the MyData.db file to the project
- Choose the correct build action property for it, like a resource
- Get the path for app resources, DBPath = App.PathToResources + "MyData.db"
- connection = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath)
- Read/write data with SQL queries

I haven't found anything that works. It seems impossible to include a db file in my project AND access it in the code.

The question is, how do I build the data into my app? What's the right paradigm here?

Thank you.

Comment: do you need to write to this database?

Comment: Hi Jason, I think I can manage without writing to it. But it would be simpler if I can write.

Comment: if you need to write, the db file must be copied to an app folder on startup, because the app bundle itself is read only

Comment: For the time being I can't even locate the db file in the bundle... How do I do that? Where do I store the file, what build action do I give it and how do I access it from the code? It sounds so basic, but that's where I'm stuck now...

Comment: it depends on how you added it - if its Content (at least on iOS) you should be able to access the file directly.  If it's a resource, it's not a file, you have to access it as a resource.  Android also has the option of adding it as an Asset, which is accessed via AssetManager.

Comment: if you want to use the existing database, you need to include the existing db as an embedded resource. Since embedded resource cannot be edited, In the application startup code, you need to read the embedded resource stream and write the database file to your application folder and then you can use the same file for opening the SQLite connections and make subsequent changes to the db.

Comment: To access a prepopulated SQLite database in xamarin, try following the steps:
1.Create the database file.
2.Place the database file to each platform, For Android, add the file to the Assets folder and set the build action to **AndroidAsset**. For iOS, add the file to the Resources folder and set the build action to **BundleResource**.
3.Install the SQLite.Net-PCL plugin to each project 4.Copy the database file from the application bundle to the mobile device to make the db file writable(if needed) 5.Create the model class and database connection class to perform the work.

Answer (score 1):

--> It's a partial solution, for now writing to the database is not working.

I found a video that precisely answers this question, by kc70: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQtNynTLhl4.

Here is a summary of it in 10 steps:

1- Create a Xamarin Mobile app

2- Choose Master Detail, with UWP

3- Add SQLite-net-pcl to the shared project

4- In Models/Item.cs

```
- Add Using SQLite;

- Change string id to int

- Change the references to that too in Services/MockDataStore.cs and Services/IDataStore.cs
```

5- New folder Data

6- New RestaurantDatabase Class in Data:

```
using SQlite;

public class RestaurantDatabase
{
    static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

    public Restaurant()
    {
        string DatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Restaurant.db");
        Assembly assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
        Stream embeddedDatabaseStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ExampleMobile.Restaurant.db"); // NameOfProgram.NameOfDB.DBExtension
        
        if (!File.Exists(DatabasePath))
        {
            FileStream fileStreamToWrite = File.Create(DatabasePAth);
            embeddedDatabasestream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            embeddedDatabaseStream.CopyTo(fileStreamToWrite);
            fileStreamToWrite.Close();
        }
        
        Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DatabasePath);
        Database.CreateTableAsync<Item>().Wait();
    }

    public Task<List<Item>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        return Database.Table<Item>().ToListAsync();
    } 
}
```

7- In App.xaml.cs

Add to App class:

```
   private static RestaurantDatabase restaurantDatabase;
    public static  RestaurantDatabase RestaurantDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            if (restaurantDatabase == null)
            {
                restaurantDatabase = new RestaurantDatabase();
            }
            return restaurantDatabase;
        }
    }
```

8- In mockdatastore.cs replace

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(items);
        }
```

With

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        return await App.RestaurantDatabase.GetItemsAsync();
    }
```

9- Copy the Restaurant.db file to the shared project

10- Set DB property to embeddedresource

Comment: If you've solved the issue, please accept you solution as the answer.

Comment: It says I can do it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, don't forget to accept your soluion as the answer. It will be beneficial for other community members who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Database file is neither a project file, nor an embedded resource file which could be added to the project. Instead the database file is created when you initially launch the application and open a SQLite connection. So you need to make sure your mobile app has permissions to access the file storage. If you have the file storage permissions, the SQLite APIs create a database file for you, when open the connection you have to specify the database file path including the file name and extension. I highly recommend you to use `EntityFrameworkCore` code first approach to create, access and manipulate the databases. you can refer the following [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/xamarin). When you specify the connection string to the database, if the file already exists it opens connection, else it can create a db file for you.

Comment: this is completely wrong.  It is absolutely possible to include a pre-populated database file with your app bundle